# Calculating relative score by number of votes

Tags: probability

Consider that 3 different game/movies got

> A: 9.1 in 8000 votes and another got
>
> B: 9.3 in 500 votes, and yet another got
>
> C: 9.5 in 60 votes

What is the best formula to rank them for comparison. i.e I want to predict what could be the rating of C & B if 8000 votes were cast for them so as to compare with A.

Is there an online calculator for the same? Also I don't have access as how each individual rated them. So I cant know the number of people who rated 10, 9, 8 etc individually but they can all rate from 1 to 10.

Comment: What are the accepted inputs for a vote? Can I vote $-1$? Add to your post.

Comment: There is no "best" formula. For example, IMDB uses a pretty complex one to "normalize" the scores, but in the end, without further detail, it's hard to give any answer to your question.

Comment: Voted to close as too broad per 5xum's point. This is not the place to discuss the relative merits of different recommandation systems. But if you pick a scoring model, I'm sure there are people here who will help you with math pertaining to it.

Comment: "So I can't know the number of people to rated 10,9,8 etc individually". Ok, but you can tell us what the possible votes are. Is it 0-10, 1-10? In practice, do people usually vote 7-10? You obviously have more information than me. You need to put some of it into the question. Until then I am voting to close as unclear what you are asking.

Comment: BTW, welcome to MSE! You may find the [tour](http://math.stackexchange.com/tour) helpful. Please look [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation) for info on formatting math for this site.

Comment: The votes can be from 1 to 10

Answer (score 1):

Your question does not have an answer.

To explain:

> Would you rather have a glass of fine whiskey or 10 litres of foul smelling, but drinkable, water?

Well, if you are a rich man in a house with good plumbing in a country with lots of water, I presume you will pick the glass of whiskey (if you drink alcohol, of course, but you get my point)

On the other hand, if you just came out of a desert to an oasis and are offered the same alternative, you probably won't think twice and will take the water, right (especially if you, say, have to go *back* to the desert for 2 days)?

---

The point is that the quality of the selection (whiskey and water) depends heavily on the circumstances you are in, and it's the same with your example.

- If your votes are extremely homogeneous (i.e., all voters vote more or less equally), then even 60 votes may be enough to conclude that movie C is the best. For example, if these are votes from 60 well known critics.
- The other extreme may be that votes fly all over the place, In that case, the result is inconclusive
- Another case may be that the movie gets better reviews in the beginning and worse in the end. For example, the average score of movie A after 60 votes may have been 9.7, in which case you might actually claim movie C is not as good as movie A.

Comment: May be of interest https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Welch%27s_t-test but as was written before, we need more data. The circumstances are also important.